# How to fix 'node is undefined' error when a default value is being passed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, trie

I am trying to implement Trie data structure in javascript. Inside the print function which just prints an array containing all the word in the trie, I have another function search, which searches for all words in the trie and pushes them to the array. search function two parameters 'node' and 'str' which both have default values. When I invoke the function without passing any argument the error occurs although the node has a default value and is not undefined.

```
this.print = function(){
        let words = new Array();
        let search = function(node = this.root, string = new String()){
            if(node.keys.size != 0){
                if(node.isEnd() === true){
                    words.push(string);
                }
                for (let letter of node.keys.keys()){
                    search(node.keys.get(letter), string.concat(letter));
                };
            }else{
                (string.length > 0) ? words.push(string) : undefined;
                return;
            }
        };
        search();
        return words.length > 0 ? words : null;
    };
```

TypeError: node is undefined     trie.js:44:16

```
search http://127.0.0.1:5500/trie.js:44
print http://127.0.0.1:5500/trie.js:56
<anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:5500/trie.js:
```

Comment: It seems like this.root is undefined

Comment: I have already defined this.root outside the this.print function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.print = function(self=this){
    let words = new Array();
    let search = function(node = self.root, string = new String()){
        if(node.keys.size != 0){
            if(node.isEnd() === true){
                words.push(string);
            }
            for (let letter of node.keys.keys()){
                search(node.keys.get(letter), string.concat(letter));
            };
        }else{
            (string.length > 0) ? words.push(string) : undefined;
            return;
        }
    };
    search();
    return words.length > 0 ? words : null;
};
```

Comment: The change is to alias this to self inside the function to prevent confusion of which 'this' is being referred to.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer if it fixed your problem so others can benefit, too.